# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface - Filesystem\DriverInterface

Tags: magento2.3, fatal-error, interface

Suddenly I started getting following error on Magento 2.3 website, on product listing page, home page and other pages are working fine:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface in /var/www/html/gemsonem2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/gemsonem2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory-&gt;createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/gemsonem2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-&gt;create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /var/www/html/gemsonem2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-&gt;get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /var/www/html/gemsonem2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-&gt;create('Webkul\\S3amazon...')
#4 /var/www/html/gemsonem2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(250): Magento\Framework\Obje in <b>/var/www/html/gemsonem2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php</b> on line <b>116</b>
```

I have searched through and applied all given solutions, at various similar post on Magento community & Stack Exchange, but none of them helped, I have already cleaned all cache & generated folders, ran all Magento commands like setup:upgrade, di:compile etc, but nothing helped, checked and confirmed that no module or extension is overriding Driverinterface, and as I said this error started suddenly even without any change in code in last 10 days. Also checked file permissions, but nothing is wrong there too.

Did I miss something to check.?

Comment: Look into Webkul\\S3amazon plugin, it might. See if there is an update for it.

Comment: Thank a lot for pointing it out, but thats strange, Webkul module was disabled long ago and I haven't enabled it, not sure why it got enabled automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from the webkul extension.

1. Disable that webkul extension.
2. Run the following commands.

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento setup:di:compile

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

   php bin/magento cache:flush

   chmod -R 777 generated var pub

Then check your frontend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if you see comments, I already mentioned that it was disabled and not sure why it got enabled automatically again, while I didn't change anything form my end, can you point out on that please..?

Comment: see why it got enable again, that not idea, may be some one other do this which working on this site.

Comment: no one is working except me

Comment: Sir, if possible can you have a small look at question:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341656/vimeo-video-refused-to-connect

Need your expert help there, 3 days and no one responded.

Comment: Yes let me check this, mean while if above answer help you please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.